# Create wordpress theme license code

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there any way to create license code per buyer for `wordpress` theme. and disable theme if license code is incorrect?
something like software license and registration code

Comment: There can be many ways to conditionally disable a WP software. But they could be removed programmatically.

Comment: Instead of trying to disable a plugin/theme if the license is incorrect, focus on offering support, upgrades and answers to personal questions if they pay for the license.